# Phaser 3 Circular Dependency Issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework, circular-dependency

## How to solve a circular dependency in Phaser 3

### Background

I'm making a game with Phaser 3, TypeScript and Parcel. I have added some classes that implement some interfaces but the interfaces import and use each other. I started using eslint with airbnb ruleset. One of the rules they implement is `import/no-cycle` But I feel like my game **needs** it.

### Example code

#### GameInterface.ts

```js
import { Scene } from 'phaser';
import PlayerInterface from '../../entities/player/PlayerInterface'; // circular

interface GameInterface extends Scene {
  player: PlayerInterface;
}

export default GameInterface;
```

#### PlayerInterface.ts

```js
import GameInterface from '../../scenes/game/GameInterface'; // circular

interface PlayerInterface extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
  scene: GameInterface;
  speed: number;
}

export default PlayerInterface;
```

### Question

A "Player" is added to the "Game" and the Player Class has a scene. So they both need to be in the interface. Since this is only a type file can I ignore this rule? Or is there a cleaver restructure I can do?

### Edit 1

Additionally [here](https://github.com/joe-lloyd/space-ship-maintenance) is a link to the full repo.

### Edit 2

Here are the 2 classes that implement these interfaces.

#### Game.ts

```js
class Game extends Scene implements GameInterface {
  player: PlayerInterface;

  constructor() {
    super({
      key: 'Game',
    });
  }

  preload(): void {
    /* preload code */
  }

  create(): void {
   /* create code */ 
  }
}
```

#### Player.ts

```js
class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite implements PlayerInterface {
  scene: GameInterface;

  constructor(scene: GameInterface) {
    super(scene, x, y, 'player');
    this.scene = scene;
    this.scene.add.existing(this);
    this.scene.physics.add.existing(this);
  }

  static preload(scene: GameInterface): void {
    /* preload */
  }
}
```

As you can see the game class creates the player, but the player is also passed a scene when created.

Comment: can you try putting both interfaces in the same file?

Comment: I'm not sure that you logic is right. Here you describe an infinite recursive javascript object that look like that: `player = { scene: { player: { scene: { player: ... } } } }`. Do you really manipulate this type of object?

Comment: Why not put the interfaces together into a file?

Comment: You should design your application in a way that one of those interfaces don't need another one.

Answer (score 1):

firs of all **Circular Dependency** means when you have two class `A` & `B`:

- Class `A` uses class `B`, so `A` is depended on `B`
- Class `B` uses class `A`, so the `B` is depended on `A` too

As the result, on initialing both classes it goes throw an infinite loop because it wants to create class A based on B, and class wants to be created based on class A though it went to benefit loop.

[image]

So just cut the unnecessary dependency.

1. So in the `Game` class, it seems you didn't need to use `PlayerInterface`.
2. And also u didn't need to extend from `Scene` and `Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite` in your interfaces. Because you are extending them in your concrete classes already. Just remove them.

Comment: The circular dependency comes only from my interfaces. I do use both player and game in each of the classes. I just don't show them in the code here because it bloats out the question. I will test removing the scene and sprite from the interface though but I feel like it gave me errors before.

Comment: FYI removing the scene/sprite from the extend is bad. they interface does not represent what it is if i remove that. If i remove it from the class it doesn't work because the intreface is incorrectly implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Place both Interfaces in the same file. This will get ride of the circular file loading which is what is tripping you up here.

Comment: This is not a scalable solution